# Force login just for dialog component

Tags: spring-security, vaadin, spring-boot-security

I configured and tested security feature in general for views according description in vaadin documentation: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/security/enabling-security

I use

```
<dependency>            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>       </dependency>
```

and added `@PermitAll` to one of my views and user is forced to login.

What Im asking for is the following scenario:

Id like to have a view without login (security) so I added `@AnonymousAllowed` to it. Works well, no login required. In this view, I open a dialog (dialog.open()). And Id like this dialog to be secured, so that if the user want to see the content of the dialog, it has to log in. Tried to add `@PermitAll` to the dialog but doesnt change anthing. I assume, that the dialog is opened in the context of the view where I added `@AnonymousAllowed` as its not a separate view, just a dialog. Is their any way of forcing the dialog to require login? Maybe, before opening the dialog call a "doLoginNow" method from any of the vaadin / spring security classes?

Asked in Vaadin forum, tried different approaches according to documentation, e.g. `@PermitAll` or working with `AuthenticationContext`, but this doesnt work or just provide methods for information about context.

Comment: Add logic around the creation / opening of the dialog - so that it can only be opened if your user is logged-in. If that's not what you want, redirect the user to the login page of they try to open the dialog.

Comment: Okay - via AuthenticationContext I can check if the user is logged in. I thought there might be a automatism like the annotation for views (@PermitAll) to redirect automatically. But understood this doesnt work for dialogs. Nevertheless, can you please describe how redirecting to login page would work?

Comment: This requirement seems to be a bit odd because a dialog is just a HTML element and does not require navigation. Why must it be a Dialog?

Comment: Id like to avoid to discuss the requirement here. If you´d like we can discuss it 1:1. Im asking if force login for just a dialog is technically possible or not. And if its possible, how. For sure it not has to be a dialog, but this doesnt answer the question. Maybe you could help out with some more technical details @SimonMartinelli? How to route the user to the login page if not logged in?

Comment: If you created the project with start.vaadin.com you can use authenticatedUser.get() and if this returns Optional.empty you just do UI.getCurrent().navigate(Login.class)

Comment: This works, but get another problem for which I create a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76934994/keycloak-springboot-vaadin-sso-integration-and-ui-navigate-problem

Comment: Please add your solution as the answer or delete the question

Answer (score 0):

Check if user is authenticated via AuthenticationContext. If not, redirect to @PermittAll view with UI.getCurrent().getPage().setLocation("securedPage");